# Capturar listas con librería re Python

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo problemas para capturar listas con la librería re de Python, por ahora estoy usando la siguiente estructura:

```
elif re.match(r'\[\s*((".*?"|\'.*?\'|\d+\s*,\s*)*)\d*\s*\]', coincidencia):
    identificadas.append(('CONST', coincidencia, 'LIST'))
```

El problema principal es que no detecta las listas anidadas. El resto de posibles elementos dentro los captura bien, además, si alguien sería tan amable de explicarme a profundidad todos los pro tips de la librería estaría sumamente agradecido. Gracias por leer.

Aviso: Esto es de un proyecto que estoy llevando a cabo con un amigo, estamos creando un lenguaje de programación, Hasya, cualquier persona interesada avise al ds: zick9510

Comment: ¿Listas anidades con elementos de cualquier tipo, así `"[ 1, 2, \" tipo ][\", 4, [ 'a', 'b',']']]"` ?

Comment: Listas anidadas en el sentido de:
[1, 2, [3, 4, "A"], [ "B", [5], 6 ]]

Comment: Si pueden contener un string, el string puede contener los delimitadores [ y ]. Tienes que identificar los string primero y luego buscar las listas. En lugar de expresiones regulares hago un recorrido lineal sumando los [ y restando los ]. Cuando la suma es cero, estás fuera de cualquier lista.

Comment: El código en cuestión identifica correctamente todos los tipos de datos sean bool, int, float, complex, str y list. El problema recae en que no clasifica correctamente las listas si contienen otras listas dentro de si. Si se encuentra un string dentro de la lista, el cual esta compuesto por "[]", no presenta problemas, la cuestión recae cuando se intenta clasificar una lista (digamosle, principal) con otras listas dentro (pongamosle, secundarias).

Comment: ¿Usas un parser recursivo?

Comment: El funcionamiento es el siguiente:
Analiza el codigo que escribiste y en base al tipo de dato que son se le asigna una estructura, el programa resuelve esa estructura, ejemplo:
print(LISTA[0] in LISTA)
El programa evalua LISTA en el indice 0 y despues se pregunta si ese resultado esta en lista, como está, devuelve verdadero, y el print muestra "Verdadero" y así con todas las estructuras, va iterando sobre la cadena principal hasta que sea irreducible, es decir, no hay elementos que se puedan reemplazar por otros equivalentes ( como un print, asignar un valor a una variable, etc.).

Comment: El parser debe ser recursivo, no iterativo. Al ser recursivo puede auto-invocarse para resolver una substructura. En este caso, cuando el parser está procesando una lista y se encuentra con otra inserta, se llama a si mismo para procesar la lista incluida. Cuando esta llamada vuelve, el parser puede seguir con el siguiente elemento.

Comment: Bueno, gracias.

Comment: Creo que regex puro no les va a servir, sobre todo por estructuras recursivas y repetitivas, como ahora. Según mi experiencia (y supongo la de muchos) hay un mejor camino: tokens y reglas. No puedo decir mucho en comentarios, pero busquen sobre el tema. Si quieren tener una buena base, ply y pyparsing son dos modulos muy buenos para hacer lenguajes de programación (el ultimo es mucho más facil de entender y usarben mi opinión). Suerte! Mas palabras claves y más relevantes: lexer, parser